# stretching histogram of image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I'm trying to implement a function `imshow(img,[])`, using the following formula
for each pixel:

```
(img(x,y)-min(img))/(max(img)-min(img))*255
```

But I got a different result
How can I stretch the histogram without using `imshow(img,[])`
tnx

[image]

code:

```
IAS=input('please enter image address','s');
Iimg=imread(IAS);
stimg=(Iimg-min(Iimg(:)))/(max(Iimg(:))-min(Iimg(:)))*255;
subplot(1,3,1)
imshow(stimg);
title('strechself');
subplot(1,3,2)
imshow(Iimg);
title('original image');
subplot(1,3,3)
imshow(Iimg,[])
title('imshow(img,[])');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its probably due to the wrong use of `max` and `min`.

You are doing `min(img)` and that will give you an array of the minimum of each row. if you want the absolute minimum of the whole image, you should call `min(img(:))`

Therefore, change your line to:

```
img=(img-min(img(:)))/(max(img(:))-min(img(:)))*255
```

**Note that its just 1 line**. In Matlab you don't need to access each pixel (`img(x,y)`) and change independently as in other languages, you can do it directly.

Additionally, if img is not a `uint8` , I suggest you make it (because you are using 0-255 scale)

```
img=uint8(img);
```

**EDIT** : Having a look to your results, very probably your original image is an `uint8`, therefore, **before** the line to strech the image, you should add the following line:

```
img=double(img);
```

So you can make divisions and keep the numbers. Else, you are performing integer division, so  34/255=0

Comment: tnx,I tried your code, but still I got a different result

Comment: Can you show the pictures the please? @abbasmahmudi

Comment: @abbasmahmudi I eddited my answer

Comment: i tried your code again but,result picture be white

Comment: Ander Biguri dear.tnx. it worked. this code finaly is necessary uint8(img)

Comment: @abbasmahmudi Great! Then, could you pelase accept the answer so other people that may have the same problem can se the solution? Its the big green tick below the number in my answer.